# The (non-covariant) extended polynomial in the propagator calculation (in Weinberg's QFT text)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, propagator

This is from Chapter 6.2 "Calculation of the Propagator" in Weinberg's QFT Volume I.

The propagator is computed to be:
$$
 - i \Delta_{\ell k}(x,y) \ = \ \Theta( x^0 - y^0 ) \int \frac{d^{3}\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3 2 \sqrt{ \mathbf{p}^2 + m_n^2 }} P_{\ell k} \left( \sqrt{ \mathbf{p}^2 + m_n^2 } , \mathbf{p} \right) e^{i p \cdot (x-y)} \\
 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ + \Theta( y^0 - x^0 ) \int \frac{d^{3}\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3 2 \sqrt{ \mathbf{p}^2 + m_n^2 }} P_{\ell k} \left( - \sqrt{ \mathbf{p}^2 + m_n^2 } , - \mathbf{p} \right) e^{-i p \cdot (x-y)}
$$

Where $P_{\ell k}(p) = P_{\ell k}(p^0, \mathbf{p})$ is a polynomial function in the momentum defined only for on-shell momenta $p^0 = \sqrt{ \mathbf{p}^2 + m_n^2 }$. The polynomial $P_{\ell k}$ is general and depends on the kind of fields you're looking at (ie, as Weinberg puts it, for a spinless scalar field it's $P(p) = 1$, or for a spin 1 vector field it's $P_{\mu\nu}(p) = \eta_{\mu\nu} + m^2 p_{\mu} p_{\nu}$).

In Equation (6.2.10), he $extends$ the definition of $P_{\ell k}(p)$ for all momenta (ie, for $any$ $p^0$, not necessarily just on-shell). He says that we can write:
$$
P^{(L)}_{\ell k}(p) = P_{\ell k}^{(L)}(p^0,\mathbf{p}) = \begin{cases} \ P_{\ell k}(p_0,\mathbf{p}) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mathrm{for\ } p^{0} = \sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2 + m^2 }  \\
\ P^{(0)}_{\ell k}(\mathbf{p}) + p^0 P^{(1)}_{\ell k}(\mathbf{p}) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mathrm{for\ }p_{0} \neq \sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2 + m^2 } 
\end{cases}
$$

Where $P^{(0)}_{\ell k}(\mathbf{p})$ and $P^{(1)}_{\ell k}(\mathbf{p})$ are polynomials just in $\mathbf{p}$.

My Question: Why do we care to extend the definition of these polynomials? I only vaguely can follow his arguments from here on out in the Chapter, because I don't understand why we even care to extend the definition.

I understand that in the end the propagator is written as a fourier transform over momenta $p$ which are not necessarily on-shell. And I think that we don't want to restrict our propagators to have their momentum on-shell. Is this the reason? I can't see another reason...

Comment: I think Weinberg wants to write it in a manifestly covariant form, which is the case after the extension. This allows him to make contact with, e.g., other definitions of the propagator such as the inverse of the free-term differential operator in the lagrangian which comes from the path-integral approach. It is also much nicer to work with that covariant expression in explicit calculations as you have the whole power of 4D fourier transform so that momentum space calculations get tractable.